# oracle sql multigrouping

Tags: sql, oracle, select, combinations

I have Oracle 11.2 DB and interesting question.

I happened to have a table being like

```
USER_ID ROLE_ID  
user1   role1  
user1   role2  
user1   role3  
user2   role1  
user2   role4  
user3   role2  
user3   role6  
user3   role5  
user4   role1
```

My target is to get the least number of roles to get all users covered. in this case it should be role1+role2

My thoughts were that I should:

1. Get all available combinations like

   1st role of 1st user + 1st role of 2nd user +....1st role of nth user
   1st role of 1st user + 1st role of 2nd user +....2nd role of nth user
   ....
   nth role of 1st user + nth role of 2nd user +....nth ro
   le of nth user
   so i get all possible combinations
2. I need to remove duplicates from all that rows i got
3. After removing duplicates i need to get the row with the least length/least number of separators

The problem is I have no idea how to get all possible role combinations. I tried experementing with "connect by level" but didn't even got close to what i expect.

Can someone help please?

Comment: IN your question there is a (possible suggested) assumption that the newest `role` is the one with the highest digit. Assuming that this is the case, you could count the number of users for which you have records for each specific combination (e.g. 15 users with role1, 27 with role2, etc.). Then, simply pick those roles where the number of users for each role matches the total number of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem.  Here is a way to do it as long as the number of roles in your system is less than 128.  (Anything larger than 128 distinct roles will cause `BITAND` to fail).

The approach relies on making a powerset ("P") of your set of roles and then finding the set ("Q") containing members of "P" that cover all the users.  Then, it finds the members of "Q" having the fewest distinct roles.

No promises on performance here.  It's a brute force approach, but combination-type problems often require brute force.

```
with user_role_data (USER_ID, ROLE_ID) AS (
SELECT 'user1','role1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'user1','role2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 'user1','role3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 'user2','role1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2','role4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3','role2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3','role6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3','role5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user4','role1' FROM DUAL )
-- End of sample data
, 
distinct_roles as ( SELECT distinct role_id FROM user_role_data ORDER BY role_id),
numbered_roles as ( SELECT power(2, rownum-1) role_ps_id, role_id FROM distinct_roles),
-- There will be 2**n entries in the powerset, where n = the number of distinct roles
ps_driver as ( SELECT rownum-1 ps_id FROM DUAL connect by ROWNUM <= power(2, ( SELECT count(*) FROM distinct_roles))),
-- Create a powerset of all the roles.
powerset as ( 
  SELECT psd.ps_id, r.role_id
  FROM   ps_driver psd
  CROSS APPLY ( SELECT  nr.role_id
                FROM    numbered_roles nr
                -- Note: this bit requires that the # of roles be less than 128.
                WHERE   bitand(nr.role_ps_id, psd.ps_id) > 0 ) r ),
-- Build a summary of each power set, just for display purposes
powerset_summary as (
  SELECT ps_id,         
         listagg(role_id,',') within group ( order by role_id ) role_list
  FROM   powerset
  GROUP BY ps_id ),
-- Get the sets the cover 100% of the users and the size and contents of each set
ps_users as ( 
  SELECT   ps.ps_id, 
           count(distinct urd.user_id) covered_users, 
           count(distinct ps.role_id) required_roles,
           ( SELECT role_list FROM powerset_summary pss WHERE pss.ps_id = ps.ps_id ) role_list
  FROM     powerset ps
  INNER JOIN user_role_data urd ON urd.role_id = ps.role_id
  GROUP BY ps.ps_id
  HAVING count(distinct urd.user_id) = ( SELECT count(distinct urd2.user_id) from user_role_data urd2 ) 
  )
-- List the sets that cover all the users with the fewest number of roles
select * from ps_users
order by required_roles
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

> ```
> +-------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
> | PS_ID | COVERED_USERS | REQUIRED_ROLES |  ROLE_LIST  |
> +-------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
> |     3 |             4 |              2 | role1,role2 |
> |    33 |             4 |              2 | role1,role6 |
> |    17 |             4 |              2 | role1,role5 |
> +-------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
> ```

#### Oracle 11.2 Compatible Version

```
with user_role_data (USER_ID, ROLE_ID) AS (
SELECT 'user1','role1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'user1','role2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 'user1','role3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 'user2','role1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2','role4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3','role2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3','role6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3','role5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'user4','role1' FROM DUAL )
-- End of sample data
, 
distinct_roles as ( SELECT distinct role_id FROM user_role_data ORDER BY role_id),
numbered_roles as ( SELECT power(2, rownum-1) role_ps_id, role_id FROM distinct_roles),
-- There will be 2**n entries in the powerset, where n = the number of distinct roles
ps_driver as ( SELECT rownum-1 ps_id FROM DUAL connect by ROWNUM <= power(2, ( SELECT count(*) FROM distinct_roles))),
-- Create a powerset of all the roles.
powerset as ( 
  SELECT psd.ps_id, nr.role_id
  FROM   ps_driver psd 
  CROSS JOIN numbered_roles nr 
  WHERE  bitand(nr.role_ps_id, psd.ps_id) > 0 ),
-- Build a summary of each power set, just for display purposes
powerset_summary as (
  SELECT ps_id,         
         listagg(role_id,',') within group ( order by role_id ) role_list
  FROM   powerset
  GROUP BY ps_id ),
-- Get the sets the cover 100% of the users and the size and contents of each set
ps_users as ( 
  SELECT   ps.ps_id, 
           count(distinct urd.user_id) covered_users, 
           count(distinct ps.role_id) required_roles,
           ( SELECT role_list FROM powerset_summary pss WHERE pss.ps_id = ps.ps_id ) role_list,
           dense_rank() over ( order by count(distinct ps.role_id)) result_number
  FROM     powerset ps
  INNER JOIN user_role_data urd ON urd.role_id = ps.role_id
  GROUP BY ps.ps_id
  HAVING count(distinct urd.user_id) = ( SELECT count(distinct urd2.user_id) from user_role_data urd2 ) 
  )
select * from ps_users
where result_number = 1
order by required_roles;
```

Comment: unfortunately as i stated in OP I only have Oracle 11.2 so CROSS APPLY and FETCH FIRST functions are not recognized. Replacing CROSS APPLY with JOIN works sometimes, but in most cases not. Is there any other way target can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

One method is an iterative approach.  Start with one role:

```
select r.*
from roles r
where (select count(*) from user_roles ur where ur.role_id = r.role_id) =
      (select count(distinct ur.user_id) from user_roles ur);
```

Then two:

```
select r1.*, r2.*
from roles r1 join
     roles r2
     on r1.role_id < r2.role_id
where (select count(*) from user_roles ur where ur.role_id in (r1.role_id, r2.role_id)) =
      (select count(distinct ur.user_id) from user_roles ur);
```

And continue until the query returns one or more sets of roles.

In 12+, you can set this up using a recursive CTE.  You could set this up using `connect`, but running multiple queries like t his might be a faster route to the solution.